# How to pass json string to web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, fiddler

I am trying to pass string to web api method. The string is json string. But when passing the below string through fiddler only part of string is passed.

> "{"Name": "Manas", "Age": "28"}"

When passing the above string only `"{"` this part is received by web api.

Can you please confirm what's is going wrong here.

Following is the web api.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Method1([FromBody]string formData){
    string encrypted = Security.Security.Encrypt(formdata);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your content type in fiddler is json. Example:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:11111
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 83
```

Also pass json in your body without "

```
{"Name": "Manas", "Age": "28"}
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't noticed that you expect a string... If you really need so, you could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Method1([FromBody]string formData){
    string data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    string encrypted = Security.Security.Encrypt(data);
}
```

Comment: Nope this won't work it will be considered as object and also the argument in the method is of method

Comment: Updated my answer.